# Using info from another program

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that accesses a game, while it is running, and uses its information (like score) in the background and will make popup overlay windows!

Now the popup windows I can figure out later,  so for now I am only interested in the ability to read information from one program that is running and use it in mine.  I also want to be able to give this program to a friend who plays the same game and have him use it as well, not sure if that is important.

I would prefer to use Java for this as it is the language I am most familiar with, but I'm willing to learn new code!

Comment: Unless this game is storing this information somewhere on your hard drive while playing, good luck. I'm not convinced Java is the kind of language you'll want to use for this, though.

Comment: @JordiCastilla: Would you like that open a popup with info on your running Fallout 4 game?

Comment: if you want to communicate between two programme, you can use TCP / UDP socket to communicate. There may be better solution to this necessity

Comment: @Stultuske There are also games (simulators typically), which are happy to expose their internal state through UDP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is how can you access the information from the game you are interested in:

- Does the game provide some API you can use - probably not?
- As mentioned by Stultuske, is the information available on disk in a format you know?
- Is the information you want on screen? Like the score? Then you could grab the screen regularly and extract the information from there. This can be done in java, I did that once for a card game (to count cards), but it involves rather academic topics like region-detection, binarization, feature-extraction and pattern recognition.
- If the information is only available in the process memory, you could try to identify the address that holds the infos you are interested in and read the memory at that address. I dont know if this can be done with java or if you need some language that is closer at the operating system level and could use Win API functions like `ReadProcessMemory`. Again, this will be quite complex - it will be non-trivial to identify the memory region, and it involves security things, like: Is your program allowed to read the memory of the game process.

Comment: Hello my friend, my game does have an API, but it doesn't have the information that I am looking for listed.  Oh well, thank you for your time.  It seems what I want to do is a bit out there.